# VHDL if-else condition order

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

Any idea what is the difference betweet this:

```
p_persist_reg_CRC_calc: process (Clk_50Mhz)
begin
    if falling_edge(Clk_50Mhz) then
        if crc_rx_init <= '0' then
            flash_crc_calc <= (others =>'1');
            else
            flash_crc_calc <= (others =>'0');
        end if;
    end if;
end process p_persist_reg_CRC_calc;
```

and this:

```
p_persist_reg_CRC_calc: process (Clk_50Mhz)
begin
    if falling_edge(Clk_50Mhz) then
        if crc_rx_init <= '1' then
            flash_crc_calc <= (others =>'0');
            else
            flash_crc_calc <= (others =>'1');
        end if;
    end if;
end process p_persist_reg_CRC_calc;
```

The second stack to zero.
In my understanding they should be the same as function.
Regards,
Emil

Comment: *The second stack to zero* isn't can't be interpreted in this context. Absent a [mcve] your question can't be answered with any degree of certainty. The use of the relational operator `"<="` would yield both if statement conditions true in giving different values for `flash_crc_calc` in the two processes if `crc_rx_init` is a scalar value (where relational ordering is by enumeration value).  Provide a context clause and declarations for the signals involved. It doesn't seem likely you want to use "<=" in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a typo: try

```
if crc_rx_init = '1' then
```

( '0' and '1' are both `<= '1'` )

Comment: "==" is a syntax error in VHDL.  For the conditions `crc_rx_init <= '0'` and `crc_rx_init <= '1'` the operator "<=" has four values less than  or equal to '1' for std_ulogic `('U', 'X', '0', '1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H', '-')` and three less than or equal to  '0'. The OP likely meant "=" if describing hardware for synthesis. The question can't be answered with any degree of certainty without a [mcve] showing declarations, context clause and an actual problem statement.  Might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the ==. As I said *most likely* a typo as `<= '1'` is very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Assuing crc_rx_init is a std_logic, then the only difference is likely in simulation.
Remember, std_logic has 9 states ('U', '0', '1', 'X', 'Z', 'L', 'H', 'W', '-'). In the first case, if crc_rx_init was 'U', then flash_crc_calc would be all '0'. In the second case, flash_crc_calc would be all '1'.